# Right way to get minimum and maximum value from variables

Tags: c#

I need to get minimum and maximum values from different variables. i getting variable values xMin, yMin, xMax and yMax and i need to find minimum xMin value, minimum yMin value, maximum xMax value and maximum of yMax value.

I write code that work:

```
double xmin , ymin  , xmax  , ymax = 0;

double[][] arrayMinMax = new double[4][];

for (int m = 0; m < 4; m++)
{
    arrayMinMax[m] = new double[shapes_id.Count];
}

for (int m = 0; m < shapes_id.Count; m++)
{
    GetBounds(out xmin, out ymin, out xmax, out ymax);

    arrayMinMax[0][m] = xmin;
    arrayMinMax[1][m] = ymin;
    arrayMinMax[2][m] = xmax;
    arrayMinMax[3][m] = ymax;
}

xmin = arrayMinMax[0].Min();
ymin = arrayMinMax[1].Min();
xmax = arrayMinMax[2].Max(); 
ymax = arrayMinMax[3].Max();
```

GetBounds return me values for each shape, and i need find minimum and maximum points of all shapes together.
shapes_id.Count return me number of shapes.

This code work ok, but i am still noob with c# and i want to know is that i wrote is right code from something like this or maybe there is better way.

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid building entire arrays if you're only interested in some of the values. Here's an example that immediately discards the previous `max` or `min` value when a bigger or smaller value is found.

```
double xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax;
xmin = ymin = double.PositiveInfinity;
xmax = ymax = double.NegativeInfinity;

for (int m = 0; m < shapes_id.Count; m++)
{
    double x1, y1, x2, y2;

    GetBounds(out x1, out y1, out x2, out y2);

    xmin = Math.Min(x1, xmin);
    ymin = Math.Min(y1, ymin);
    xmax = Math.Max(x2, xmax);
    ymax = Math.Max(y2, ymax);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the values you store in your arrays later on? If no, you could just determine min and max values in the loop. So you have iterate only once an not 5 times.

```
double xmin = double.MaxValue, ymin =double.MaxValue , xmax = double.MinValue, ymax = double.MinValue;

foreach (var shape in shapesId) {
   double txmin, txmax, tymin, tymax;
   GetBounds(out txmin, out txmax, out tymin, out tymax);
   if (txmin < xmin) xmin = txmin;
   if (tymin < ymin) ymin = tymin;
   if (txmax > xmax) xmax = txmax;
   if (tymax > ymax) ymax = tymax;

}
```

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but txmin (for example) can always be >0 than I wold get xmin value 0? I need first GetBounds for xmin,ymin etc, and than use foreach, right?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, the minvalues should be initialized with double.MaxValue and the maxvalues with double.MinValue

Answer (score 0):

```
double max(double[] a){
    double max = a[0];
    for(int i = 0;  < a.Length; i++){
       if(max < a[i]) max  = a[i];
   }

return max;
}
```

min in similar way.

Then invoke `max(arrayMinMax[1]);`